# What is the best way to insulate already existing stud wall against block foundation?

Tags: insulation, foundation, basement-refinishing, basement-insulation

I am doing some remodeling in the bathroom of a bi-level. I removed the wood paneling and found the stud wall directly against the concrete block foundation with batt insulation only in the cavities. This is a brick house and in between the exterior red brick and stud walls are Styrofoam panels. I have only had water leakage once, when the water table was extremely high.

What would the best way to insulate this stud wall that is against the block foundation wall?

Comment: IIUC, moving from the outside in, you have a brick wall and Styrofoam in some places, but a block wall with a stud framed wall and fiberglass batts in the stud bays in other places? Are the block walls below grade and the brick walls above grade? Is there any sign that the fiberglass insulation (and studs) are now or ever have been wet?

Comment: There are lots of similar questions to be found. [For example](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/88718/how-to-insulate-already-existing-stud-walls-along-block-foundation?rq=1), right out of the Related list at right. Did you search at all? Answers depend on your location/climate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insulate already-existing stud walls along block foundation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/88718/how-to-insulate-already-existing-stud-walls-along-block-foundation)

Comment: I did see that post, but I have styrofoam and no gap at all inbetween my stud frame and the block wall. Starting from the floor going up, block wall (below grade) with stud frame flush against it going halfway up the frame. Then styrofoam panels start the rest of the way to the roof. On the other side of the styrofoam is a brick wall. The styrofoam starts a little above ground level.  It’s a unique situation with no signs of mold or wetness but this house is 43 years old.